# display all records of database table in div in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

here it showing all records from database but it shows all empty div first then below it shows all records .i want to show each record to be shown in single div in rows.

```
<div id="winnercontainer">
<h2 style="background-color:#9966FF; width:850px; height:30px; font:bold; font-  size:22px; color:#FFFFFF; padding-left:20px;">Winners</h2>
<?php 

include('pagination/ps_pagination.php');
 $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$conn) die("Failed to connect to database!");
$status = mysql_select_db('gunjanbid', $conn);
if(!$status) die("Failed to select database!");
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM winners';
$pager = new PS_Pagination($conn, $sql,10, 10);

//The paginate() function returns a mysql result set for the current page
$rs = $pager->paginate();
?>


<table>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
?>
<div id="winner">
<tr>
<td ><img src="memberpic/myphoto.jpg" width="150" height="150"  alt="001" /></td>
<td >&nbsp;</td>
<td ><table >
  <tr>
    <td >Auction Item :&nbsp;<?php echo $row['Items']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rs.&nbsp;<?php echo $row['Rs']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Winning Bid Value : Rs.&nbsp;<?php echo $row['WinningBidValue']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MRP : Rs.&nbsp;<?php echo $row['MRP']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Auction closed on :&nbsp;<?php echo $row['enddate']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Winner :&nbsp;<?php echo $row['Winner']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>City:&nbsp;<?php echo $row['City']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Delivery Status:&nbsp;<?php echo $row['DeliveryStatus']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  </table></td>
   <td >&nbsp;</td>
  <td  id=save><font color=black>SAVED:</font>&nbsp;Rs.<?php echo $row['MRP']-  $row['WinningBidValue']; ?></td>
  <td >&nbsp;</td>
  <td ><img src=productimage/1/1.1.jpg width="200" height="193" alt="001" /></td>
   </tr>
 </div>

  <?php 
}
?>
</table>

<?php
//Display the navigation
//echo $pager->renderFullNav();
echo '<div style="text-align:center">'.$pager->renderFullNav().'</div>';
?>
</div> 


  abd my stylesheet s are

    #winnercontainer
    {
   width:870px;
     height:auto;
     background-color:#CCCCCC;
     border:solid #9966FF;
   border-radius:10px;
   margin:auto;
   clear:both;
   margin:10px;
   position:relative;
   }
  #winner
  {
width:840px;
height:250px;
background-color: #999999;
border: solid #9966FF;
border-radius:10px;
margin:auto;
clear:both;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 15px;
position:relative;
   }
```

i want all my records to be place in div means each div have one record to be display.plz help me ,i am new here.

Comment: my advice... learn html first

Comment: I hope that `<tr  div id="winner">` is just a typo error and not the actual code. Otherwise, do as slash197 said

Comment: @slash197 sir may i know the reason to learn html.

Comment: @user3419125 If you're developing web applications then knowing html is kind of a prerequisite!

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a start with some old code I have that reads a table from a MySQL database and prints it out on a screen. You can modify it as you see fit. It's a php file that resides on the server.

```
<?php
echo "<head><title>Read list</title></head>";

$host     = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$user     = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname   = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}

$query = " select * from list where uniqueid >= 0 ";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("could not query database");

echo "<table cellpadding=1px border=1>";
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
         $uniqueid = $row['uniqueid'];
         $localid = $row['localid'];
         $mdid = $row['mid'];
         $type = $row['type'];
         echo "<tr><td>".$uniqueid."</td><td>".$localid."</td><td>".$mdd."</td><td>".$type."</td></tr>";
         }
echo "</table>";
?>
```